# .bat file for launching Jupyterlab with julia

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab

I always type the commands below on CMD to launch jupyterlab:
[cmd]

```
julia
using IJulia
jupyterlab()
```

I wanted to automate this process and I tried writing a .bat file `test.bat` and running it on CMD:

[test.bat]

```
echo "launching jupyterlab..."
julia
using IJulia
jupyterlab()
end
```

However, CMD stops reading the commands after reading the command `julia` at 2nd line, meaning, it doesn't run `using IJulia` and `jupyterlab()`.

What is going on and what should I do?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using julia in evaluate mode like this:

```
julia -e "using IJulia; jupyterlab()"
```